# I want to filter the array according to the given search input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a grocery site in which I want to filter the grocery items according to the search input given by user. This filtered grocery items must be shown on the screen. I have returned the following code but when I log the value of `filterDisplay` on console after searching, it shows object with 0 enteries.

```
function Search() {
  const [word, setWord] = useState("");
  const [filterDisplay, setFilterDisplay] = useState({
    key: "",
    name: "",
    quantity: "",
    price: ""
  });

  function handleChange(event) {
    let oldList = grocery.map((groceryToLower) => {
      return {
        key: groceryToLower.key,
        name: groceryToLower.name.toLowerCase(),
        quantity: groceryToLower.quantity,
        price: groceryToLower.price
      };
    });

    if (event !== "") {
      let newList = [];
      setWord(event);
      newList = oldList.filter((name) =>
        name.name.includes(word)
      );

      setFilterDisplay(newList);
    } else {
      setFilterDisplay(grocery);
    }
  }

  console.log(filterDisplay);

return <input name="search" onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Search" />
```

Comment: What is `grocery` in your code snippet. `word` state won't be updated for the check int he filter. Also, issuing side-effects, like logging, in the function body of a functional component can have odd results, try logging in an `useEffect` hook with dependency on `filterDisplay` instead. Can you provide a more complete example that includes some test data and example results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are updating `word` with `input event` which is wrong and you should be using `event.target.value` which is the actual word. I did some work around this, you can try this code. Created [stackblitz example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-fcss5p)

```
function Search() {
  const [filterDisplay, setFilterDisplay] = useState([]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    const word = event.target.value
    if (!term) {
      setFilterDisplay(grocery); // assuming `grocery` is list of items
    } else {
      setFilterDisplay(grocery.filter(g => g.name.toLowerCase().includes(word)))
    }
    console.log(filterDisplay);
  }
  return <input name="search" onChange={handleChange} placeholder="Search" />
}
```